# Hibernate Criteria: Nested Subquery (select * from (nested results))

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, subquery

I have a **raw sql query** which I need to write in hibernate **criteria**.

The **raw sql query** I have is:

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            Table t1 
        ORDER BY Sort1 DESC, Sort2 DESC, Sort3 DESC
    )
GROUP BY Age 
ORDER BY Sort1 DESC, Sort2 DESC, Sort3 DESC
```

What it does is,

1. Sort the t1 table results as per `ORDER BY Sort1 DESC, Sort2 DESC, Sort3 DESC`
2. Select a single row per Age group
3. Sort the grouped results as per `ORDER BY Sort1 DESC, Sort2 DESC, Sort3 DESC`

**Note) the reason why I need Step 1) before Step 2) is because `GROUP BY`, be fault, doesn't guarantee ordering and I need to have strict ordering applied to pick the single row per Age group**

I have a table as below: 
**Table t1**

```
| ID |  Lastname  |  Firstname |  Age |  Created_at | Sort1 | Sort2 | Sort3  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    Jolie   |   Angey    |  40  |    2011     |   3   |   2   |   1
| 2  |    Pitt    |   Brad     |  41  |    2012     |   2   |   1   |   2 
| 3  |    Smith   |   Casey    |  40  |    2010     |   3   |   1   |   2
| 4  |    Smith   |   Carey    |  40  |    2009     |   3   |   2   |   3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result returned from the above sql query is as follows:

```
| ID |  Lastname  |  Firstname |  Age |  Created_at | Sort1 | Sort2 | Sort3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4  |    Smith   |   Carey    |  40  |    2009     |   3   |   2   |   3    
| 2  |    Pitt    |   Brad     |  41  |    2012     |   2   |   1   |   2
```

Seems like **DetachedCriteria** is the way forward, and saw some solutions that use results from DetachedCriteria feeding to ***where* clause**, but **not directly after *FROM***.

So I made the subquery using DetachedCriteria, but not sure where to go about completing Criteria..

```
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Some.class, "a")
        .addOrder(Order.desc("a.Sort1"))
        .addOrder(Order.desc("a.Sort2"))
        .addOrder(Order.desc("a.Sort3"));

// stuck from below... :( 
Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(??)
      .add(Projections.groupProperty("Age"))
```

I would much appreciate your insight into how to go about doing it. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why can't you eliminate the subquery? Or, even better, write a wrapper and just use hibernate's NativeQuery

Comment: Im building this on top of legacy code which is all in hibernate criteria. Would prefer to move on to other methods before exploring all possibilities with hibernate criteria. Also, i need the current subquery to return results that i want.